# Visual Basic 6.3 (en Excel) - Grabar en archivo en distintas columnas

Tags: vb6

Estoy trabajando con Visual Basic y desde un formulario, tras el ingreso de 2 datos, necesito grabar en un archivo de manera Random los mismos.

Mi problema es que cuando lo grabo en un .xls, inserta los datos en la misma columna:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que el primer Dato vaya a la Columna A y el segundo a la B. También lo que me sucede es que no puedo hacer grabar los datos uno abajo del otro (como una tabla).

```
Sub Grabar()

10 Rem Graba en disco en modo RANDOM
20 Open "C:\CCA\Final\prueba.xls" For Random As #1 Len = 50
30 Put #1, , regi
40 Close #1
50 MsgBox "Grabado en archivo"

End Sub
```

El tipo de dato es el siguiente y está declarado en el principio del módulo

```
Public regi As camion


Type camion
tipo As String * 45
peso As String * 2 '
End Type
```